# MacOS SpriteKit - Resize UI When User Resizes Window

Tags: swift, windows, macos, user-interface, sprite-kit

I'm building a `MacOS` `SpriteKit` game using `Swift`. I've run into a problem since MacOS windows are resizeable, my UI is not visible when the window is shrunken.

I have done quite a bit of research, but there doesn't seem to be any good tutorials on how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There aren't many good resources for macOS development. Most of the Swift community is focused on iOS.

Comment: Show your code in the view controller.

Comment: This is why constraints exist

Comment: I'm using SpriteKit. My UI is in SpriteKit.

Comment: yes, you should be setting a static size with your game scene, using a proper scale mode, and have constraints on the skview that resizes with the window

Comment: Similar question without answer: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/96073